# Herokuで「認証アプリケーションで生成されたコードを入力」と出てログインできない

Tags: heroku

Herokuにログインしようとしたところ、
「アカウントを保護するため、ID の検証を行います。

認証アプリケーションで生成されたコードを入力します。」
と出るのですが「認証アプリケーションで生成されたコード」というのが何を意味するのか分からず、また、ログイン出来ないためアプリケーションのページにも行くことができません。どうすればいいでしょう？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

認証アプリケーションというのは [Google Authenticator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.authenticator2)のようなアプリかと思います。これを使ってアカウントを登録すると、アプリ側でコードを見れます。

バックアップコードさえ紛失した場合は[問い合わせる](https://help.heroku.com/7IDU8QZZ/what-should-i-do-if-i-m-locked-out-of-my-heroku-account#:~:text=If%20you%20have%20lost%20access%20to%20the%20MFA%20device%20and,open%20a%20ticket%20with%20us.)必要があります。

参考: https://devcenter.heroku.com/ja/articles/two-factor-authentication

Comment: ログイン出来ないのでDashboardでQRコードを読み込むということができません。

Comment: もし過去にauthenticatorで認証済みで、認証したということ自体を忘れたならバックアップコードが必要です。それさえ紛失したなら、herokuのサポートサイトで探してみてなさそうならサポートチケットを作成するのが良いと思います。他の可能性としてはアカウントが乗っ取られたというのもありますが、サポートセンターに問い合わせるのが一番でしょう。https://help.heroku.com/JYBXPRFN/before-opening-a-ticket

Comment: 多要素認証ができなくなった場合の問い合わせ先が書かれてます。https://help.heroku.com/7IDU8QZZ/what-should-i-do-if-i-m-locked-out-of-my-heroku-account#:~:text=If%20you%20have%20lost%20access%20to%20the%20MFA%20device%20and,open%20a%20ticket%20with%20us.